# XML listview overlaps elements when setting visibility

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, view

I have an xml layout of about 3000 lines, which serves as the layout for a questionnaire type of app. Each page of the questionnaire is inside of a different linear layout and I set the visibility of the linear layouts in code using `View.GONE` or `View.VISIBLE`. This way the user can navigate through the pages without loading new `intents` each time.

However, when I navigate fast through the app (just pressing the **next** `button` to go through the screens), some of the elements that are supposed to be `View.GONE` shows up and overlaps over the **VISIBLE** items. This only happens with linear layouts that have list views inside of them. For all the other pages.

I can scroll fast through them, but just the ones with list views in the `View.GONE` elements sometimes shows up when I navigate too fast. How can I fix this ? Let me know if you want code ... however the xml is very large.

T.I.A.

**EDIT**

This is a sample of my xml code, I have 3000 lines of this repeating in my xml...

```
  <LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/package_normal_samplesblood"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="70dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_heading_b1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="23sp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
            android:textColor="#6f6f6f"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:text="Blood Samples"/>

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/button_samples_blood"
    android:text="Add Blood Samples"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>

    <ListView
    android:id="@+id/listview_samples_blood"
    android:scrollbarSize="0dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    /> 
        </LinearLayout>
       <RelativeLayout
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:background="#ffffff"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="75dp"
android:layout_marginTop="-75dp"

>
        <View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="#DEDEDE"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"/>
<ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/left9"
            android:background="@null"
            android:scaleType="fitEnd"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_width="70px"
            android:layout_height="70px"
            android:src="@drawable/left"/>
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_heading2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textColor="#6f6f6f"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="RhODIS®"/>
<ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/right9"
            android:background="@null"
            android:scaleType="fitEnd"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_width="70px"
            android:layout_height="70px"
            android:src="@drawable/right"/>
 </RelativeLayout>
 </LinearLayout>


  <LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/package_normal_sampleshair"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="70dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_heading_b2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="23sp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
            android:textColor="#6f6f6f"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:text="Hair Samples"/>

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/button_samples_hair"
    android:text="Add Hair Samples"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>

    <ListView
    android:id="@+id/listview_samples_hair"
    android:scrollbarSize="0dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    /> 
        </LinearLayout>
       <RelativeLayout
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:background="#ffffff"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="75dp"
android:layout_marginTop="-75dp"

>
        <View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="#DEDEDE"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"/>
<ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/left10"
            android:background="@null"
            android:scaleType="fitEnd"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_width="70px"
            android:layout_height="70px"
            android:src="@drawable/left"/>
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_heading2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textColor="#6f6f6f"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="RhODIS®"/>
<ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/right10"
            android:background="@null"
            android:scaleType="fitEnd"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_width="70px"
            android:layout_height="70px"
            android:src="@drawable/right"/>
 </RelativeLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
```

And then this is a sample of how I show and hide the linear layouts in code, this repeats for 24 left buttons and 24 right buttons:

```
left24.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            package_normal_welcomescreen.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            package_normal_package_details.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            package_normal_openbag.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            package_normal_kitnumber.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            package_normal_emptybag.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            package_normal_gpscoordinates.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            package_normal_image_scene.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            package_normal_samplesblood.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            package_normal_sampleshair.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            package_normal_samplestissue.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            package_normal_sampleshorn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            package_normal_samplesother.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            package_normal_packsamples.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            package_normal_returnbag.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            package_normal_sealreturnbag.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            package_normal_image_sealedbag.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            package_normal_scanned.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            package_normal_animal_details.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            package_normal_animal_horn_details.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            package_normal_animal_ears.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            package_normal_area_details.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            package_normal_collecter_details.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            package_normal_additional_information.setVisibility(View.GONE);

             package_normal_owner_details.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
             package_normal_owner_details.bringToFront();
        }
    });

    right24.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            if(Session.signatureIsCaptured)
            {
            package_normal_welcomescreen.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            package_normal_package_details.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            package_normal_openbag.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            package_normal_kitnumber.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            package_normal_emptybag.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            package_normal_gpscoordinates.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            package_normal_image_scene.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            package_normal_samplesblood.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            package_normal_sampleshair.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            package_normal_samplestissue.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            package_normal_sampleshorn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            package_normal_samplesother.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            package_normal_packsamples.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            package_normal_returnbag.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            package_normal_sealreturnbag.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            package_normal_image_sealedbag.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            package_normal_scanned.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            package_normal_animal_details.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            package_normal_animal_horn_details.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            package_normal_animal_ears.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            package_normal_area_details.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            package_normal_owner_details.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            package_normal_collecter_details.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            package_normal_additional_information.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            package_normal_additional_information.bringToFront();
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(Screen_Package_Normal.this, "Authorized Signature Required", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }

    });
```

I have different types of listviews and adapters, custom and android built in. I don't think the problem lies with the adapter since it works pretty well displaying the listviews and the problem occurs even before the listviews are populated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a temporary fix, not sure how correct this is as an answer, but this fixed my problem... I applied this to my entire layout, and it adds an animation when I hide and show layouts, thus slowing them down a bit, removing the overlapping elements from showing up.

This is what I added to my layout:

android:animateLayoutChanges="true"

Comment: My solution is to call `requestLayout()`.